# Pasar grupo de checks desde una vista a un contralador como lista o como listado, mediante un modelo complejo c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Saludos 
La cuestión es que tengo un modelo complejo el cual estoy invocando datos desde 2 modelos normales para llevarlo a pantalla y crear una pantalla con multiples check con la intención de guardarlos mediante un ActionResult

Aqui el modelo complejo que hereda de otros modelos

```
namespace SeguridadWeb.Models
{
    public class ProfileExtendTypeComplex
    {
        public ICollection<Type> TypeProfileExtend { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProfileExtended> ProfileExt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

cuando se lleva a la vista se llena una tabla usando la siguiente linea de código

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TypeProfileExtend)
                    {
                        List<ProfileExtended> permiso = (from itemProfileExt in Model.ProfileExt
                                                         where itemProfileExt.idProfileExtendedType == item.idType
                                                         select itemProfileExt).ToList();

                        <tr>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                                @if (permiso.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    @Html.Hidden("hdidProfileExtended_" + item.idType.ToString(), permiso[0].idProfileExtended)
                                }
                                @Html.Label("label_" + item.idType.ToString(), item.nameType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.CheckBox("chkProfileExt_" + item.idType.ToString(), permiso.Count > 0 ? Convert.ToBoolean(permiso[0].value) : false, new { @id = "chkProfileExt_" + item.idType.ToString() })

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
```

con el boton de enviar hacia el controlador para realizar la insersion de los datos

```
<input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
```

la vista se encuentra de esta forma a nivel de html
[image: Vista de la pantalla]

El problema es cuando se trata de guardar la información me esta llegando al controlador como null

este es el controlador que estoy usando

```
// POST: ProfileViewModel/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([[Bind(Include = "idProfileExtended,idProfileExtendedType,value")] ProfileExtended ProfileExtended)
        {
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.ProfileExtended.Add(ProfileExtended);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                       return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    //}
                }


                return RedirectToAction("ProfileComplex/CreateEdit");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

alguna idea de que podría ocurrir o de que estoy haciendo mal?

Agradeciendo de antemano agradeciendo su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, has probado en cambiar el parámetro de tu acción `Create`a `ProfileExtendTypeComplex` ?? una cosa así `public ActionResult Create(        ProfileExtendTypeComplex profileExtended)`

Comment: Saludos, en efecto estuve probando varias cosas, pero al parecer cuando se realiza el guardado de por el boton de guardado llega a la clase como null

Comment: Hola. Puedes cambiar el parámetro a `FormCollection collection` y verificar si en los datos del Post te llegan?

Comment: Saludos, al usar el FormCollection collection los mismos, llegan pero solo llegan los nombres de los campos mas no los id's requeridos

Answer (score 0):

En una lista es mejor usar ciclos for en lugar de foreach.

Por ejemplo:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].idGuess)
}
```

Usalo ya específicamente de acuerdo a tu requerimiento. Si tienes dudas en específico, no dudes en comentar y con gusto lo verificamos..

Comment: Saludos en efecto he estado leyendo eso, el problema es cuando se trata de usar el modelo complejo se pierde al enlazar los datos

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, despues de leer bastante encontre este sitio que me ayudo a encontrar la respuesta, basicamente cuando se usan modelos complejos debes indicarle cual es la tabla y el valos al cual te estas referenciando para el el mvc lo entienda.

por ejemplo si antes usaba idPerfilPaginaahora deberia llamarla como PerfilPagina.idPerfilPagina

LKes dejo el link del enlace https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/